# Server error in application : cannot create ActiveX component

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I running this code on the main PC and it is working properly but when this shared with users and connect to the main PC (server) there is an error returned as "Server Error In '/' Application"

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlHvj.png)

```
    Dim objAccess As Object = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\Users\Main\Desktop\Project1\App_Data\Book.mdb")
    objAccess.DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport("Export-Book")
    objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase()
    objAccess.Quit()
    objAccess = Nothing
```

Any help please

Comment: Perhaps this article may be of help. Note the last entry in this forum.  http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?655541-Cannot-create-ActiveX-component-problems

Comment: The solution is not working